# To find the number of distinct real roots of the equation.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5) ,\  x\in \mathbb{R}$. 
The no. of distinct real roots of the equation $\frac{d}{dx}\cdot f(x)=0$ is exactly??

As far I got into my thoughts is that....If a 2nd derivative of the function is positive then orignal function is an increasing function. If it is strictly positive then orignal function is monotonic increasing and the graph will cut the x axis at one point so we have exactly one real root. Also , the no. Of roots are equal to the degree of the equation.
But this function doesn't seem an increasing one...Is there any other method to solve these kind of questions.
Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Think about this : between two roots, there is a maximum or a minimum. Then ???

Comment: Sketch the graph of $f$, using what you know about the roots of $f$ and what sign it has at any point (you don't need any more detail than that). How many tops and bottoms must it at least have? Could it possibly have more?

Comment: If it helps conceptually, you can invoke the fundamental theorem of Algebra to see that since $f$ would be a $5^{th}$ order polynomial, the derivative would be $4^{th}$ order, and you'll have a maximum of 4 possible distinct solutions. Will these actually be distinct or will there be repeated roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$, so $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $4$. Recall that a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ distinct roots.

Now, Apply Rolle's theorem to $f$ restricted to the interval between consecutive roots of $f(x)$, that is, to the intervals $[1,2]$, $[2,3]$, $[3,4]$ and $[4,5]$. For each of these intervals, Rolle's theorem says that there exists a point $c$ in the interior such that $f'(c) = 0$. So, we have found four distinct roots of $f'(x)$, and so these are all the roots.

---

As an aside, it is true that if $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(x)$ is increasing. However, an increasing function can have $f''(x) < 0$, like $f(x) = \log (x)$.

It is also true that if $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, but it is not necessary that every such function will cross the $x$-axis at some point, for example, consider $f(x) = e^{x}$.

Comment: Thank you @brahadeesh......Rolle's theorem works in the case. Your 2nd explanation about function is really doubt clearing.thanks for ur time.

Comment: ..Would Rolle's theorem work in all such kind of problems? Like I have been encounter with couple of problems which uses max-min notion to find out the roots...Is there any universal method of solving such kinda problem? I m a begginer in calculus.

Comment: I really doubt there is one universal method for solving such problems, but Rolle's Theorem and the Mean Value Theorem are two tools that one must know because they are very helpful in a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to roughly sketch $f(x)$. Notice that $f(x)$ is of odd degree and has a positive leading coefficient. Hence $\lim _{x\to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim _{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$. Now if you draw a line starting from the third quadrant through the roots of $f(x)$, you will cross the $x$-axis 5 times and end up going up into the first quadrant. Apply Rolle's theorem to the curves through the roots. How many zeroes will the derivative have?